# jquery animate not working for negative values in version 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i am using the jquery version 1.7.1  and using animate function.

```
$(ele).animate(
{
    y:-370
}
{
step:function(now)
{
   $(ele).attr("y",now);
});
```

animating the y value by step function. for negative value **it returns Nan** but for **positive value it is working fine.**

but this issue occured in version 1.7.1 of jquery.

```
**this one working fine in latest jquery version.**
```

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: can you create a demo in fiddle

Comment: You've some errors in your code, but apart from that, it works as expected for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2WDe7/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that your code is not correct and further I can't see a problem in what you've shared to us. It seems to me that your problem sits somewhere else...

```
var ele = $("div");
$(ele).animate({
    y: -370
}, {
    step: function (now) {
        $(ele).attr("y", now);
    }
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2WDe7/1/

**Update**

If this doesn't work for you, try to set an initial-value and animate from this, maybe from `0` downwards:

```
var ele = $("div");
$({y: 0}).animate({
    y: -370
}, {
    step: function (now) {
        $(ele).attr("y", now);
    }
});
```

Comment: in your fiddle u referred jquery 1.7.2 am using jquery 1.7.1

Comment: am animating the rectangle element of svg. but it is working fine in  jquery 1.9.1 version

Comment: i am using same code which u posted in your response.but first time it returns Nan and then it returns -370.

Comment: how can i do this $({y: 0}).animate with out using element in animate ?

Comment: You don't need to specify an element, an object-literal works too... http://fiddle.jshell.net/2WDe7/2/

Comment: @SivaRajini Is your question answered for now? Then mark it as it is! :)